# JSON Transformation using JOLT

Tags: html, json, transformation, jolt

I would like to transform the below input JSON using JOLT. what will be the JOLT Spec?

**INPUT JSON--**

```json
[
  {
    "Bank": [
      {
        "id": "101",
        "PuneBranch": [
          {
            "id": "449",
            "address": "Wakad",
            "IFSC": "IEC_62196_T1",
            "MICR": "123"
          },
          {
            "id": "450",
            "address": "Hinjewadi",
            "IFSC": "IEC_62196_T2",
            "MICR": "456"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "102",
        "BangaloreBranch": [
          {
            "id": "451",
            "address": "Whitefield",
            "IFSC": "IEC_62196_T3",
            "MICR": "789"
          },
          {
            "id": "452",
            "address": "EC",
            "IFSC": "IEC_62196_T4",
            "MICR": "012"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Expected Output--**

```
Bank 1
ID: 101

PuneBranch 1
id: 449
address: Wakad
IFSC: IEC_62196_T1
MICR: 123

PuneBranch 2
id: 450
address: Hinjewadi
IFSC: IEC_62196_T2
MICR: 456

Bank 2
ID: 102

BangaloreBranch 1
id: 451
address: Whitefield
IFSC: IEC_62196_T3
MICR: 789

BangaloreBranch 2
id: 452
address: EC
IFSC: IEC_62196_T4
MICR: 012
```

Basically, Jolt SPEC should contain HTML tags to show the images and excepted output. Can this be achieved using a jolt? Is this feature is provided by the jolt library?

Comment: Hi Kaushal, can you make the expected output a valid JSON please?

Comment: Hi Barbaros, I'm not sure what would be the expected output JSON? Could you please help me get the expected output using jolt?

Comment: it should be just like the one you provided as input JSON

Answer (score 0):

While the expected output is not presented in JSON format, the desired spec presumably might be like

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        " Bank": "=intSum(@(1,id),-100)",
        " id": "=(@(1,id))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. 
Can we add HTML data in jolt spec that will show the expected output as mentioned in the question?

HTML data:
<b>Bank 1</b></br>
ID: 101</br></br>
&#127974;PuneBranch 1
<ul style="list-style-type: square;">
<li>id: 449</li>
<li>address: Wakad</li>
<li>IFSC: IEC_62196_T1</li>
<li>MICR: 123</li>
</ul>
&#127974;PuneBranch 2
<ul style="list-style-type: square;">
<li>id: 450</li>
<li>address: Hinjewadi</li>
<li>IFSC: IEC_62196_T2</li>
<li>MICR: 456</li>
</ul>

Comment: you're welcome @KaushalKothari , unfortunately Jolt is a library which transforms from JSON to JSON, but not produces HTML code.